# "No builders" error GrailsClasspath when running grails run-app

Tags: grails, gradle

When running grails run-app I get the following error:

```
| Error Error initializing classpath: No builders are available to build a model of type 'org.grails.gradle.plugin.model.GrailsClasspath'. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: do other commands work? what is the origin of the project (freshly created, checked out from somewhere)? what grails version (guess 3)? is this error from your IDE or on plain command line?

Answer (score 0):

This is logged as an unresolved issue presently: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-12079

I'm seeing this same issue with both grails 3.0.11 and 3.1.1. I was able to get around it for my project by installing grails 2.4.5 then executing `grails set-grails-version 2.4.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the problem where i took an existing grails project. That grails project was specified as 3.0 but actually contained many references to 2.5 in the build.gradle

Had To make changes to the gradle configuration to make it run.
To get you on track: create a new app somewhere and compare the gradle configuration between the 2